# notifications doesn't close when route changes antd

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

In my react app I need to close all notifications on current tab when i go to another tad.   antd version "^4.20.7". Notifications open and close through antd api.

I know that i can do it directly in the component, but maybe is it some solutions to add this functionality to all notifications in whole app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `destroy` method to get rid of all notification generated.

In your case you would just need to `notification.detroy()` when another tab is clicked.

To add this functionality to all notification that exists inside your app you would simply need to handle the notification state in redux or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by creating a hook that monitors the change of the route and inserting it in the App component and wrapper class Notification that store notification key. I used `close` method instead of `destroy` because when using `destroy` notification disappear without close animation.

```
class Notification {
  key = '';

  constructor() {
    notification.config({
      closeIcon: <CrossIcon />,
      maxCount: 1,
    });
  }

  open(config: ArgsProps) {
    this.key = `notification-${Date.now()}`;

    notification.open({
      ...config,
      key: this.key,
    });
  }

  close() {
    notification.close(this.key);
  }
}

function useNotificationClose() {
  const {pathname} = useLocation(); // React Router v6 hook

  useEffect(() => {
    Notification.key && Notification.close();
  }, [pathname]);
}

function App() {
  useNotificationClose();

  return ...your app components
}
```

Note: this will work when `maxCount` set to 1 as in my case.